# jsf f:ajax render ony if value in execute not null or empty

Tags: ajax, jsf, render

I have a trouble with my jsf page. I do not know how can make ajax render only when "input" not null or not empty.

Here is my code:

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{control.query}"/> 


<h:commandButton id="search" value="Search" action="#{control.getdata()}">
    <f:ajax execute="input" render="datatable"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of `rendered` attribute on the target.

```
<h:panelGroup id="datatable">
    <h:dataTable ... rendered="#{not empty control.query}">
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```